# How to invoke a C# method inside a Q# operation?

Tags: programming, q#

Suppose there is a Q# operation as follows:

```
operation Op () : Bool {

    let result = CSharpMethod ();
    return result
}
```

where `CSharpMethod ()` is a defined method in the Driver class as follows:

```
public static bool CSharpMethod () {
    // ...
    // return a boolean value
}
```

So my question is how to call a method of a C# class inside a Q# operation and handle its returned value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Q# operations are compiled into C# classes. To define a C# implementation for a Q# operation, you will need to do the following steps:

1. Define a Q# operation with empty or intrinsic body `CSharpMethod`.
2. Define a C# class that implements the abstract class into which your Q# operation gets compiled, something like `public class CSharpMethod_Impl : CSharpMethod`.
3. Define method called `Body` in that class that does the actual computation that you need and returns the result.

This is a very hacky thing to do, so you might want to follow an example of operation [`GetOracleCallsCount`](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/utilities/Common/Utils.qs#L16) and [its C# implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/utilities/Common/CounterSimulator.cs#L95) to see the exact pieces that have to be in place for it to work.

You can also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58784924/how-to-write-c-sharp-implementation-for-a-q-operation-with-intrinsic-body) on StackOverflow that tries to do a similar thing.

Comment: Thanks for your time but my question is not about defining a C# implementation for a Q# operation, but it is about calling a C# method in the Q# operation. What I intend to do in this question is different from the purpose of the question to which you referred.

Comment: I understood that. There is no way to call a C# method from Q# directly without defining a Q# operation for it, so the approach I described is your best shot at getting it to work.